# MYSQL Query that excludes falsy values

Tags: mysql

Is there an easy way in MYSQL to exclude all falsy values in one statement? It should do the following:

```
SELECT id FROM table 
WHERE id != '' 
AND id != 0 
AND id IS NOT NULL;
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Usually id field is part of primary key, so I think id always != '' and IS NOT NULL. So you put != '' (string) and != 0 (number) but which is datatype of id field?

Comment: Columns are typed, so one of `id != ''` or `id != 0` has to be invalid. The SQL standard also states that the not equal operator is `<>` even if many DBs support `!=`.

Comment: In my example `id` is not the primairy key. The id can be a varchar field or integer since the system i'm building builds this query dynamically based on a business rule like system

Comment: I think the biggest problem here is the fact that databases have no concept of 'truthy' or 'falsey' values. Either a value is a `BOOLEAN` and is directly true or false, or it's a different datatype. If it's another datatype then you need to tell it how to convert the value to true or false.

Comment: Thanks Phylogenesis! If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If we presume your column is varchar, then you can use `COALESCE` to turn `NULL`
 into one of those invalid values:

```
SELECT id FROM table 
 WHERE COALESCE(id, '') NOT IN ('', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it happens a lot of time, but I have another proposal:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COALESCE(NULLIF(field,0));
```

I hope this could be helpful to someone!